# How to become Apple iOS certified technician? is ACMT enough?

Tags: ios, repair, applecare

I cant find if ACMT (Apple Certified Mac Technician) cover also iOS devices, I work in big company full of iPhones and we send to repair at least 10 iPhones every month so it will be better to repair them at the company. What certification I need to be able to repair phone without loose warranty?

Comment: 10 phones a month is not a lot - in fact for a large company buying 10 new phones is not a lot so I expect it will not be cost effective

Comment: See my answer @mark - doing repairs yourself is one of the least important benefits of self service. Also, doing all the paperwork at your site pays for the overhead after just a couple of trips to the Genius Bar assuming you have one walking distance from the shop.

Answer (score 2):

You need both certificates so you can fix iPhones as well. Also if your company is registered as [Apple Authorized Service Provider Program](https://support.apple.com/aasp-program) you can. If you need help with the certificates one very good app. is IT Technicians Professionals on Apple Store, you have all questions up to date.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you would do anything but whole device swaps for iOS repairs due to the touch screen calibration issues. That being said - 10 a month should tip things so that the time you save arranging 10 swaps beats your current expense arranging repairs now even if you didn't benefit from any of the other great aspects of SSA.

Why not get started with the self-service page and see what the program offers you? In my experience, the access to knowledge base and the service web applications far outweighs the repair benefits. Especially helpful is the dedicated diagnostic server. If you have the required 1000 devices this opportunity is almost a slam dunk win for you.

- http://www.apple.com/support/programs/ssa/

I wouldn't go ACMT unless you a) wanted the challenge and growth opportunity for your employees b) didn't have any decent local options for AppleCare. Once you are in as a self-servicing account, training vouchers shouldn't be an issue - just allocate time to your people to take the classes and pass the tests.